# How to differentiate the scanned PDF and native PDF?

Tags: pdf

How to differentiate the scanned PDF and native PDF?

Because both the documents having the extension with PDF only.

Is it possible to find whether the document is scanned PDF or native PDF by its properties?

Comment: Could you please provide context of you question? E.g. are you going to differentiate files programmatically? What language/OS? Are you looking for document attributes or content?

Comment: Am looking for the attribute of the document to differentiate the scanned Pdf and Native Pdf manually.

Comment: *scanned PDF or native PDF* - **scanned PDFs are PDFs, as "native" as any others**. I assume you want to differentiate between PDFs which allow text extraction (because text is drawn using text drawing instructions) and those those that do not (because text is only present on embedded bitmap images). Is that correct? (There actually are other types, too, but probably not of interest for you.)

Comment: Yes, am trying to extract the text from PDF. sometimes, am also getting scanned PDF (i.e. Image). So, I need to figure out the type of PDF before sending text extraction method.